# Green's Formula as proof for harmony

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I showed this to my teacher this morning, and he remarked that the argument was a bit strange...but that it might be correct; he recommended using the ball mean property (which I will do, but I'm curious about this path)...

So, the question is: Does the following argument work? Is it a valid proof?

Partial Differential Equations, Jurgen Jost, [pg 31](http://books.google.com/books?id=gpN2cYmZg2UC&pg=PA31), problem 1.7:

Let $\Omega \subset R^3 \backslash ${$0$}$,u:\Omega \rightarrow R$ be harmonic.  Show that $$v(x_1,x_2,x_3):=\frac{1}{|x|}u(\frac{x_1}{|x|^2},\frac{x_2}{|x|^2},\frac{x_3}{|x|^2})$$ is harmonic in the region $\Omega ' := \{ x \in R^3:(\frac{x_1}{|x|^2},\frac{x_2}{|x|^2},\frac{x_3}{|x|^2})\in \Omega\}$.

Proposed solution:

$x=(x_1,x_2,x_3)\\\mu = \frac{x}{|x|}=(\frac{x_1}{|x|},\frac{x_2}{|x|},\frac{x_3}{|x|})\\\bar{\mu}=\frac{\mu}{|x|}=(\frac{x_1}{|x|^2},\frac{x_2}{|x|^2},\frac{x_3}{|x|^2})\\\frac{d\bar{\mu}}{d\mu}=\frac{1}{|x|}\\\bar{u}=u(\bar{\mu})\\\frac{\partial \bar{u}}{\partial \mu}=\frac{1}{|x|}*\frac{\partial\bar{u}}{\partial\bar{\mu}}\\v(x)=\frac{\bar{u}}{|x|}$

Since the region $\Omega ' \subset \Omega$, $\Delta \bar{u} = 0$.

Let $\Omega '' \subset \Omega '$ be $\Omega '' := \{ x\in R^3:|x| \gt \epsilon : \epsilon > 0\}$

Green's Formula writes out as:

$$\int_{\Omega ''}\{v\Delta \bar{u}-\bar{u}\Delta v\}dv=\int_{\partial\Omega ''}\{v\frac{\partial \bar{u}}{\partial \mu} - \bar{u}\frac{\partial v}{\partial \mu}\}da$$

Which rewrites as:

$$\int_{\Omega ''}\{\frac{\bar{u}}{|x|}\Delta \bar{u}-\bar{u}\Delta \frac{\bar{u}}{|x|}\}dv=\int_{\partial\Omega ''}\{\frac{\bar{u}}{|x|^2}\frac{\partial \bar{u}}{\partial \bar{\mu}} - \frac{\bar{u}}{|x|^2}\frac{\partial \bar{u}}{\partial \bar{\mu}}\}da$$

Noting that the right side equals zero and the first term on the left side equals zero, it simplifies to:

$$-\int_{\Omega ''} \bar{u}\Delta\frac{\bar{u}}{|x|}dv = 0 $$

And the non-trivial solution is $\Delta\frac{\bar{u}}{|x|}=0: x \in \Omega ''$.

And, to qualify the last step (triviality): Either $u$ is identically equal to zero, in which case $\Delta v = 0$, or $u\ne 0$, in which case $\Delta v = 0$ anyways.

Then, since $\Omega ' = lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0} \Omega '' : x\in R^3 : \frac{x}{|x|^2} \gt \epsilon \gt 0$, $\Delta v(x)=0\forall x \in \Omega'$.

I realize the above notation is sketchy, I just don't know how to apply a limit and an $\epsilon$/$\delta$ type-argument to sets; it is supposed to prevent the integration over the singularity at $\{0\}$ in order to satisfy the divergence theorem.

$\Omega ''$ and the step above was an attempt to incorporate Tomas's suggestions...but I still don't know if all the steps are valid.

Comment: I have two questions: 1 - How do you know that $\Omega'$ is sufficient smooth, so you can use the green identitie? 2 - What happens if $0\in\partial\Omega'$?

Comment: (2): if $\{0\}$ is in the domain, $\frac{1}{|x|}$ becomes a singularity.  It is likely dumped to guarantee smoothness.  
$$ $$
(1): Use of the [ball mean property](http://books.google.com/books?http://books.google.com/books?id=gpN2cYmZg2UC&pg=PA16#v=onepage&q&f=false) is required for the "correct answer."  Any function satisfying the mean value property must be smooth, according to the proof... it is sufficient that it be locally integrable and measurable in $\Omega$.  Since $\bar{\mu} \in \Omega$, it is locally integrable...because u is locally integrable in $\Omega$.

Comment: for (1), i mean the boundary of the domain, not the function. for (2), you have to avoid the singularity to use green identitie, it is possible to do this in your case?

Comment: as to measurability, looking at [this](http://zeta.math.utsa.edu/~mqr328/class/real2/Mfunct.pdf) it seems like the set of $x\in \Omega '$ encompasses every vector $\gt 0$...so I guess it is measurable.

Comment: Sorry, let me explain better. The boundary of $\Omega'$ must be at least an $C^{1}$ manifold. Take a look in the proof of the divergence theorem and you will see it asked this hypoteshis.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6161/discussion-between-tomas-and-chris-donlan)

Comment: Results of chat: Tomas identified a couple of issues with the application of the Green Identity...and so I tried to account for that by applying the Green Identity to a region whose perimeter did not include the origin (and, consequently, a singularity)...don't know if it is allowed though (or procedurally correct. 

Thanks Tomas.